# How to split a number string using a comma in every 3rd digit from the right

Tags: python, split

A beginner here! Can I ask how to split a number string in every 3rd digit from the right and put a comma in between and do it again.

```
>>>num = '12550'
```

how can I make that into this

```
>>>12,550
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this neat trick:

```
num = 123456789
print ("{:,.2f}".format(num))
```

which outputs:

```
123,456,789.00
```

If you don't want the decimal places just use:

```
print ("{:,}".format(num))
```

Comment: Oh, yeah I remember that. Thanks it really answers my question

Comment: @TheNoobProgrammer don't forget to upvote and mark this question as corerct if you find this helpful

Comment: I only have 13 reputations :(

Comment: @TheNoobProgrammer You can still upvote and use the checkmark to make this answer green (marked as correct)

Comment: Yeah I did it :)

Comment: @TheNoobProgrammer I'm afraid you didn't, you must be confused with somehting else

Comment: Don't be. I am telling the truth :)